# Teradata SQL Tuning : Joining with the same table multiple times via alias

Tags: sql, database, join, query-optimization, teradata

I am running into a `skew` situation  on  `hash join` step , which caused the CPU to spike up. From a `SQL` re-write perspective , I could find a work-around each time , with the least , using a `volatile table` that can get things going a lot faster. But since this is so pervasive I thought I'd had checked around here if there are alternate ways of approaching this problem.
So most of the SQL's run like this ( and I guess this comes from `denorming` it to `star` ) :

```
sel a.<col list of a> , b.<another list>,fct1<list >, d.c0,d.NC, d1.c1,d1.NC
d2.c2,D2.NC, d3.c3,D3.NC, d4.c4,D4.NC,<other cols from rest of the join tables> 
from
fct1 f join d on f.c1=d.c0 Join d1 on f.c2=d1.c1 Join D2 on f.c3=D2.C2 
       Join d3 on f.c4=d3.c3 


       /* D , D1 , D2 ,D3 and D4 are all views with the Exact same definition 
       i.e.  Sel * from D minus sel * from D1 Minus 
       sel * from D2...etc till D4 
       is 0    rows.
       So C0 col of D0 is the same as c1 col of D1 same as c2 of d2 ..
       till D4. And similarly, NC of D0,D1,D2,D3 & D4 is the same col
       So effectively what's happening is joining on different cols 
       from the same fct table is causing different rows from the 
       same   joining table that is repeatedly aliased 
       */
```

Joining on the same table multiple times is causing skew as D1 tables try to get joined to spooled table using a `hash join`. 
I wonder if there is any other way to rewrite the same logic 
Something like

```
case when f.c1=d0.c0 then  d0.c0 end  as d0.c0
case when f.c2=d0.c0 then  d0.c0 end  as d1.c1 
etc

from 
 f  join d on ( f.c1=d.c0 OR f.c2=d.c0 or f.c3=d.c0 etc )
```

OR if D is a small table we could `PJ` all the D's togather

```
( sel D0.c0,d0.CN from D0 group by 1,2) 
 full join ( sel d1.c1,d1.CN from D1 group by 1,2) etc
```

But for current situation , D has a high row count so `PJ's` are not worth it .
I wondered what other alternatives are there to express this kind of logic

Comment: Are there any WHERE-conditions on D? What's the PI of the facte table? If the number of rows returned by dimensions is not to large the optimizer should do a *star-join* approach, i.e product join the dimensions and then directly join to the fact-PI (I don't know if this is done when the same table is accessed multiple times)

Comment: Hi Dieter ..`Star-Join`..:) yes that is what I try to achieve most time using VT bit in it will very often combine skewed tables so `StarJ` has to deal w/ 'good' canidates but 'bad' ones joined via VT. It would do the same thing for a 'same table' situation after all its an alias ..but it turns out skewed situation  in joining back the same table again using another similar fact table column. <br> Yes there is a 'd' filter on the date range.<br>  Fact table PI (a multi col one to give good data dist. ) is different from Dim ( single PI ). TY again

Comment: `star-j` happens when PI of `fct` is a compound one that'll include the `dims`. I wondered if that is poss. to achieve within the Query itself without  the `VT`